# Perform arithmetic operations on string in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

input: `"20+10/5-1*2"`

I want to perform arithmetic operations on that string how can I do it without using `eval` method in ruby?

expected output: `20`

Comment: is there any other way to do without using eval?

Comment: you can't. what is the problem with `eval`? if you have string and you need to "evaluate" it. `eval` is the way. maybe you need change the way you're getting the input.

Comment: this question was asked by the interviewer he said that don't use the eval method. use your custom logic. I have tried but I didn't find any way.

Comment: you can break the string down, use some regex maybe. convert numbers with `to_i`, use `send` method to run operations.

Comment: You should look up the shunting yard algorithm for conversion to reverse polish notation and then reverse polish notation evaluation

Comment: @Alex I would argue there is a massive problem with using `eval`. Imagine instead of an arithmetic operation the next string contains code to send your ssh keys to an external source or to delete your disk...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I hesitate to answer an interview question, and I am completely embarrassed by this code, here is one awful way to do it. I made it Ruby-only and avoided Rails helpers because it seemed more of a Ruby task and not a Rails task.

```
#
# Evaluate a string representation of an arithmetic formula provided only these operations are expected:
#   + | Addition
#   - | Subtraction
#   * | Multiplication
#   / | Division
#
# Also assumes only integers are given for numerics.
# Not designed to handle division by zero.
#
# Example input:   '20+10/5-1*2'
# Expected output: 20.0
#
def eval_for_interview(string)
  add_split      = string.split('+')
  subtract_split = add_split.map{ |v| v.split('-') }
  divide_split   = subtract_split.map do |i|
    i.map{ |v| v.split('/') }
  end
  multiply_these = divide_split.map do |i|
    i.map do |j|
      j.map{ |v| v.split('*') }
    end
  end

  divide_these = multiply_these.each do |i|
    i.each do |j|
      j.map! do |k, l|
        if l == nil
          k.to_i
        else
          k.to_i * l.to_i
        end
      end
    end
  end

  subtract_these = divide_these.each do |i|
    i.map! do |j, k|
      if k == nil
        j.to_i
      else
        j.to_f / k.to_f
      end
    end
  end

  add_these = subtract_these.map! do |i, j|
    if j == nil
      i.to_f
    else
      i.to_f - j.to_f
    end
  end

  add_these.sum
end
```

Here is some example output:

```
eval_for_interview('1+1')
=> 2.0
eval_for_interview('1-1')
=> 0.0
eval_for_interview('1*1')
=> 1.0
eval_for_interview('1/1')
=> 1.0
eval_for_interview('1+2-3*4')
=> -9.0
eval_for_interview('1+2-3/4')
=> 2.25
eval_for_interview('1+2*3/4')
=> 2.5
eval_for_interview('1-2*3/4')
=> -0.5
eval_for_interview('20+10/5-1*2')
=> 20.0
eval_for_interview('20+10/5-1*2*4-2/6+12-1-1-1')
=> 31.0
```

Comment: is it possible to show output according to parenthesis? like 

input: (5+1)/2

output: 3

Comment: I imagine it is possible, but I certainly do not have the time to write that code. It would probably be easiest with recursion.